# wordpress enqueue a script if it hasn't already been loaded using a function

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I have created a wordpress plugin that creates various widgets. To keep page load time down, I only want to enqueue the associated scripts when the widget is being used.

To do this I created a function like this:

```
function enqueue_lightbox(){
wp_enqueue_style(
SKIZZAR_SHORTCODES__PLUGIN_SLUG . '-fancybox-css',
'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css',
array(),
SKIZZAR_SHORTCODES__VERSION
);
wp_enqueue_script( SKIZZAR_SHORTCODES__PLUGIN_SLUG . '-lightbox' );
wp_enqueue_script( SKIZZAR_SHORTCODES__PLUGIN_SLUG . '-lightbox-media' );
}
```

And in my widget class I call it like this:

```
enqueue_lightbox();
```

The issue I have is that I have 2 widgets sharing the same piece of code, so I'd like to create a statement that says, if it hasn't been enqueued elsewhere already, enqueue it.

How would I write this function?

Comment: The whole point of the enqueue system is to load scripts and stylesheets only once. Just run the enqueue function where you needed, if it has already been run it will not be loaded again, if it hasn't been run yet it will enqueue the needed files.

Answer (score 2):

You can use wp_script_is function to check the file and load it like this

```
$handle = 'fluidVids.js';
   $list = 'enqueued';
     if (wp_script_is( $handle, $list )) {
       return;
     } else {
       wp_register_script( 'fluidVids.js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'js/fluidvids.min.js');
       wp_enqueue_script( 'fluidVids.js' );
     }
```